# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string i cant find it

Tags: php

Why wont this work?

```
function user_data($user_id) {
    global $con;
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);

        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT $fields as velden FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

    }
}
```

I searched a lot but cannot find the fix.

Comment: What parameters are you passing to `user_data()`?  Where are you using `$row`?  Which line is showing this error (that's the key to debugging)?

Comment: `Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string` there's also a line number, what is it?

Comment: It is about - $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT $fields as velden FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'");

Comment: Try to print query, maybe some error in it.

Comment: Why do you have `$user_id` as a parameter to your function, then just throw away the passed value and get it from the session instead?  How are you calling `user_data()`?  What parameters are you passing?  P.S. The error is telling you that either `$fields` or `$user_id` is actually an `mysqli_result` object and not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error almost always means that the query has failed so examine the query.

Try this :

```
$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
$sql = "SELECT $fields as velden FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'";
echo $sql;
```

Now if the error is not obvious to the eye, copy the query and run it in phpmyadmin or whatever tool you use to manage your Databases.

Almost definitely this part of the query is going to cause an error if there is more than one field in your `$fields` array. `SELECT $fields as velden` so try removing the `as velden`.